# Android: Toolbar back to call logical parent

Tags: android

After clicking to back button it go to parent activity.

But I want to go its previous screen that was on the app.
[image: example]

After clicking on back it should go from Activity C to --- Activity A or Activity B according to which called activity C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a data holder class

```
public class DataHolder{
public static boolean isParentActivityA=false;
public static boolean isParentActivityB=false;
}
```

in ActivityA 
add isParentActivityA=true and isParentActivityB=false just before startActivity(intent) method and vice-versa in ActivityB;

in ActivityC

implement onBackPressed method
and add

```
onBackPressed(){
Intent intent
if(isParentActivityA)
{intent=new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
 }
else
intent=new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish()
}
```

In case of any query feel free to comment